# What is a debug.log file and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: debug

I see this annoying file at times appearing on my desktop and other folders. Here's the content of the one I just found:

```
[0104/221014.762:ERROR:directory_reader_win.cc(43)] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)
```

What is it and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-is-there-a-debug-file-on-my-computer-and-how/de0c8d1c-6db6-437b-9173-aba72b512054), it is generated by the Chrome Browser.

It is fixed [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=711159) for `88.0.4302.0`, (to be stable [Jan 19](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule)).

It seems to happen when opening an .`.html` file on any directory, Chrome generates `debug.log` in that directory.

Comment: I have the latest version: `87.0.4280.88`.

Comment: @Mori You need to wait for 88 to hit the stable channel, which as stated is scheduled for 19th January 2021.